# website Images distorted/disappear on Android browers

Tags: android, html, css

I have created a fairly simple responsive website and have optimized it for mobile use using the meta tags. It works very well on desktops and on iOS phones and even the Galaxy S5. However, based on some tests using a browser compatibility program, the design falls apart on Android devices using 4.2 or lower (including the Samsung Galaxy S2 through 4, Kindle Fire 2, and Google Nexus). The images (doesn't seem to matter what type of file) will either become very vertically stretched or disappear altogether, no matter the file type. I have tried many things and can find no apparent difference between the images that are displaying and those that are not. Also, my header and footer are no longer where they are supposed to be. From what I can tell, the problem is that Android is not interpreting my css in the same way as ios does.

I have been able to fix the problem somewhat by dictating pixel dimensions for all of the photos instead of percentages, although this messes with the responsiveness of the site. This also fixes my header/footer problem although there is a very large space on the top and bottom of the mobile drop down menu and my logo in the footer (.svg) is distorted despite giving it dimensions.

I can't seem to find any information about this problem so I feel like it has to be an easy fix that I am overlooking.

The website is www.2015housingconf.com. 
Thanks in advance!